# Resistor Failure Modes

Tags: resistors

I am new in the electronic industry and I would like to investigate more about resistors failure modes.

I have some doubts that came up when I read this article: 
http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA259655.
See pages from 3-177 to 3-183 (which is the pages 231-237 of the PDF).

1. What means "Lead Damage"?
2. What is a "Drift" parameter?
3. What is "Binding/Sticking" resistor?
4. What is a "Contaminated resistor"?
5. What is a "Seal leakage" ?

Comment: @jsotola, that "binding/sticking" one is a bit confusing since this is for a *fixed* resistor.

Comment: 1. About the term "lead": does it mean "anything that connects to the resistor", for example, a PCB trace? or does "lead" refer necessarily to a wire? 2. what is the value that changes over time? I don't think it's the resistence because the article distinguish the failure mode "change in resistor" and "drift". Is it the resistor variation with the tempeture proprierty?. 3. See Photon comment. 4-5. Got it!

Comment: @jsotola that's a valid answer, not a comment. Please use the answer box.

Comment: At 50X rated power, the resistor chars and then flames in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*lead damage* -- lead would be the wire or a connector what is attached to the resistor when it is manufactured .. it is broken off or damaged to the point that it affects the resistor performance (broken trace on a PCB is not resistor failure)

*drift* -- is the undesirable change in resistance (even though it may be predictable) ... what causes it does not really matter in this context ... a thermistor value change due to temperature change is not drift ... but a difference in resistance for the identical temperature is drift

*binding/sticking* --- variable resistor adjustment mechanics not working smoothly ... there is a possibility that a resistor expands as it gets hot and it may have a mechanical device to adjust for the expansion (grasping at straws there)

*contaminated* --- foreign substance on resistor affecting its properties (wirewound resistor that has a splatter of solder on it)

*seal leakage* --- resistor may be rated for damp environments because it is inside a sealed jacket and the jacket has a crack in it. it may also be immersed in a dialectric liquid for heat dissipation

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

*lead damage*  --- heavy bulk THT parts with long leads and no support under 15g vibration, 100g shock with resonance may cause fatigue failures.  I once had to know these specs and apply them in my 1st job in 1975 for Aerospace. ( Now all PC ATX supplies use Polyurethane adhesive for big parts, , like Home Depot pump tubes but industrial type)  *Sometimes QA rejected to Mil-stds (now IPC stds) just because they looked bad ...damage? but still worked.*

*drift* --- design tolerance error from excessive temp. coefficient on values or excessive ambient changes

*contaminated* --- ( tech sneezed and a drip of solder ended up somewhere then  spilled beer on keyboard. )

*seal leakage* --- Shipborne parts often get exposed to saltwater and must be resistant ( no pun) to salt water or corrosive cleaning fluids

From my design , test and Mfg experience , I learnt to categorize Root Cause Failure Analysis more accurately than these categories being Eng. Mgr for a Contract Mfg Mgr and Test Eng Mgr for 10yrs before that... based on ranking of history ( and old memory)

### Root Category

1. Bad Design ( Elect, Mech or Process)
2. Bad Process ( ESD handling, IE or QA )
3. Bad Parts

For manufacturing  90% of failures or more are bad soldering ( opens or insuff solder, shorts , balls, cracks etc)  but many of these are from bad layout design.  The key choice is biased where you want to focus the most effective corrective action.

One  favorite joke was an ATE test failure for tolerance on a zero ohm resistor ;)

Comment: Thank you!!! I think I understood all the topics with your help and @jsotola.